# Como pasar una consulta de sql a formato eloquent de Laravel, usando whereNotIn

Tags: laravel, eloquent

A mi consulta quería agregarle un NOT IN con esta subquery:

```
 
not in
( SELECT  h.Id_Hab 
FROM 's_solicitud' s, s_habitaciones_adj h
WHERE s.id_solicitud=h.id_solicitud
    and date_format(h.Fecha_Desde, "%d-%m-%Y") BETWEEN ('21-12-2021') AND ('26-12-2021')
    and date_format(h.Fecha_Hasta, "%d-%m-%Y") BETWEEN  ('21-12-2021') AND ('26-12-2021')
    );
```

Ahora, en mysql me anda pero cuando la intente pasar a formato Eloquent no retorna nada, nisiquiera un error. El código antes del Where Not In si funciona

```
    $habitaciones = Habitacion::where('id_destino', '=', $destino_id)->where('id_ut', '=', $esta_id)->where('id_hotel', '=', $hotel)->whereNotIn(function ($query) {
    $query  ->select('h.id_hab')
            ->from('s_solicitud AS s', 's_habitaciones_adj AS h')
            ->where('s.id_solicitud = h.id_solicitud')
            ->whereBetween('date_format(h.fecha_desde, "%d-%m-%Y")', [21-12-2021, 26-12-2021])
            ->whereBetween('date_format(h.fecha_hasta, "%d-%m-%Y")', [21-12-2021, 26-12-2021]);
})->get();

    return response()->json([
        'habitaciones' => $habitaciones
    ]);
}
```

¿Cuál puede ser error? Gracias!

Comment: Deberías obtener un error ya que `whereNotIn()` requiere que pases como primer parámetro el nombre de la columna. Por lo tanto debes tener `->whereNotIn('column_name', function ($query)...`